# Why is the first console.log not printing?

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

EDIT: Sorry. The !== was a typo. I didn't catch it until after posting. Forgive me for wasting your time.

I'm new to Javascript.

I created this function (using winston):

```
    function setlogger (log_level = "warn", logfile, screendump, format) { // defaults
    console.log("Format came into logger as: ", String(format), ". Converting..."); //777
    if ( typeof format == 'undefined') { 
        format = format.combine(
                     format.colorize(),
                     format.timestamp(),
                     format.align(),
                     format.printf(formatParams)
                    );
        console.log("Format is now:(1) ", String(format), ". "); //777
    }
    console.log("Format is now: (2)", String(format), ". "); //777
```

When I call it, the `(2)` `console.log()` shows up, but not the `(1)`.

```
Format came into logger as:  undefined . Converting...
Format is now: (2) undefined .
```

Why is this?

EDIT: UPS nevermind. Found it

Comment: You don't show how you are calling it.

Comment: I think you meant to do a typeof format === 'undefined' on the third line of your code.

Comment: You should show how you invoke `setlogger` as well

Comment: @Delvian no, the code inside is accessing `format`, i think that is intentional.

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function to trigger this output.

Comment: `typeof format !== undefined` maybe you mean this? I think undefined shouldn't use a quote, that will make it a text with the value "undefined" and String data type. Or is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Typeof does return a string

Comment: @MichaelHarley please study how `typeof` works.

Comment: Ok I don't usually used that, thanks for the information :)

Comment: Question had a fatal typo. It's a waste of people's time (I'm the author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this : `Format came into logger as:  undefined . Converting...` gets logged then this if `( typeof format !== 'undefined')`check will not pass, and the log call you have in that block will never log anything.

Your error is more logical on the kind of thing you try to achieve here, so maybe if you better describe what your intentions are we can be more helpfull

Answer (score 1):

The first `console.log` does not show because the value you passed as the `format` argument was undefined, so it didn't pass the `if` statement which required it **not** to be undefined.